# Class instantiation causing functions within said class to be executed PHP

Tags: php

I have a registration class. The problem I'm facing is that the instantiation itself is somehow causing the functions within that class to be called.

I've tested this by adding an `error_log()` directly before and after the instantiation: `$register = new Register();` every time I receive another `error_log()` which I placed inside the functions of the class that I'm instantiating.

How can I solve this?

**EDIT** this is what an example may look like:

---

**testclass.php**

```
class Test {
    public function test() {
       error_log("Function test() was run.'");
    }
}
```

**test.php**

```
require_once("testclass.php");

$test = new Test();
```

Comment: Show us an example of what this code looks like

Comment: @Darren I've edited my post adding an example of what I'm dealing with.

Comment: It's because your function, `test()` has the same name of the class `Test` so PHP is using it as the constructor and calling it when you instantiate it.

Comment: Worth noting that PHP is [moving away from this behavior](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php) in `7.0.x` and onward.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! I just don't know why someone downvoted my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your function, test() has the same name of the class Test so PHP is using it as the constructor and calling it when you instantiate it.

```
class Bar {
    public function Bar() {
        // treated as constructor in PHP 5.3.0-5.3.2
        // treated as regular method as of PHP 5.3.3
    }
}
```

As the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) say:

> Warning Old style constructors are DEPRECATED in PHP 7.0, and will be
>   removed in a future version. You should always use __construct() in
>   new code.

Comment: Thank you very much Robert. This is such an odd type of behaviour.

Comment: @Ryan no problem. This is left over behavior from PHP 4